# Boost.Iostreams vs. iostream/streambuf overloading for bitstream I/O

Tags: c++, stl, iostream, boost-iostreams

For my current task I need a possibility to read/write (mostly file based) bitstreams.
Though this is a more or less trivial task if coded in standard C/C++ I'd like
to rewrite to code using a more generic approach by overloading and using
the standard STL iostream or similar so I can write something like

```
writeHeader();
{
    ofstream outfile ("test.bin");
    outfile << true; // Write 1 bit
    outfile << false; // Write 1 bit
    outfile << (char)0x42; // Write 8 bits
}
```

However I'm not sure which road to go:

1. Using Boost.IOStream or
2. Derive from streambuf or iostream directly.

So far I never had to derive/provide my own stream classes but I want to improve my
knowledge...

Maybe someone can provide some pointers or hints which way to prefer and why!?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to make *both* a new stream class and a stream buffer class. Use the custom stream class to overload the output operators to put a single bit in the custom stream buffer.

The reason is that C++ doesn't support smaller entities than a single byte (`char`). Even the `bool` type is not a single bit, as it has to be addressable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you also have a pointer where to read about it?

Comment: @fhw72 I used to have a link to some good site the detailed stream and streambuf customizations, but unfortunately I can't seem to find it anymore.